# Why does generic_filter in scipy.ndimage get different result from opencv.Sobel

Tags: python, opencv, scipy

Here is the code for testing

```
    import numpy as np
    import cv2
    from scipy.ndimage import generic_filter
    def sobel_x_filter(P):
        return (P[2] + 2 * P[6] + P[7]) - (P[0] + 2 * P[3] + P[6])
    matrix = np.ones((100, 100))
    matrix[1, 2] = 2
    cv2_result = cv2.Sobel(np.float32(matrix), cv2.CV_32F, 1, 0)
    generic_filter_result = generic_filter(matrix, sobel_x_filter, (3, 3))
```

And the `cv2_result[1, :]` is `[ 0.,  2.,  0., -2.,  0., ..., 0.]`,

but the `generic_filter_result[1, :]` is `[0.,  0.,  0., -2.,  0.,  0.,  0., ..., 0.]`.

I am quite confused why the result is different, I tried to change the `mode` parameter in the function `generic_filter` to `mirror` or `wrap`, still it produced the same result as before and was not in line with the result of `cv2.Sobel`

Comment: The OpenCV Sobel filter takes the square root of the sum of the squares of the x and the y gradients. Your code appears to only consider the x-direction.

Comment: @MarkSetchell but i 've set the parameter xorder and yorder to 1 and 0 respectively

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't noticed the difference between the C++ and Python parameters - so that is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think your function should read:

```
def sobel_x_filter(P):
   return (P[2] + 2 * P[5] + P[8]) - (P[0] + 2 * P[3] + P[6])
```